# Changing column names in R by name not by number

Tags: r

I have a table in R which has many columns. I want to change the column names. I have found that:

```
colnames(table)[123] <- "newName"
```

changes the 123rd column to the name "newName". But to achieve this I need to find the number of the column with the name "oldName". I was thinking of something like this:

```
colnames(table)["oldName"] <- "newName"
```

but that didn't work. So how can one go about doing this?

Comment: `colnames(table)[grep('oldName', colnames(table))] <- 'newName'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite easy using dplyr's `rename` function:

```
library(dplyr)
rename(mtcars, cylinders = cyl)
```

This will rename the column "cyl" to be "cylinders" in the data set "mtcars".

Edit after comment:

If you want to rename multiple columns, you can do (without dplyr):

```
names(mtcars)[names(mtcars) %in% c("mpg", "cyl", "hp")] <- c("miles", "cylinders", "horsepower")
names(mtcars)
# [1] "miles"      "cylinders"  "disp"       "horsepower" "drat"      
# [6] "wt"         "qsec"       "vs"         "am"         "gear"      
#[11] "carb"
```

So you just need 1 line to rename multiple columns. And of course, you could store those names in vectors.

---

Note to whom it may concern: while it is true that **plyr** has a `rename` function, **dplyr** *also has* a `rename` function in its current CRAN version 0.3.0.2. It is described in the [introduction to dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) and, if you're running the current version, you can just type `?dplyr::rename`. If you look closely, you can even tell which one is being used because there's a subtle difference between plyr's and dplyr's rename functions: in plyr, it would be `plyr::rename(mtcars, c("oldName" = "newName"))` while in dplyr (like in my answer) it is `dplyr::rename(mtcars, newName = oldName)`.

---

Edit after comment by OP:

I cannot reproduce the error you describe. Here's what I understood you did, but it works without any errors or unexpected behavior in my case:

```
df <- data.frame(DE9 = 1:2, code9 = 3:4)
df
#  DE9 code9
#1   1     3
#2   2     4
dplyr::rename(df, newname = DE9)
#  newname code9
#1       1     3
#2       2     4
```

Comment: For a single column, it would be, but I don't use this route if there are multiple columns to rename

Comment: @akrun, yes, if you wanted to "bulk change" a lot of columns, your method may be better. This one is very convenient for single/few columns.

Comment: Why is the `grep` method better in bulk than the `rename`? Both seem to require one line per column. Or am I false?

Comment: @Geoff `names(mtcars)[grep('mpg|cyl|hp', names(mtcars))] <- ..`

Comment: @akrun, we should note that there's a potential difference in the behaviour if you use `grep` or not. For example, `grep("name", c("first name", "last name", "name", "names"))` will select all these columns which would be a problem if you only wanted to rename the "name" column.. of course the regex could be adjusted..

Comment: @beginneR In that case we should have word boundary `\\bmgp\\b` like that.  Also, `%in%` method also could break if there are leading/lagging spaces.

Comment: @beginneR in the example you showed,if you want the `3rd` entry to be TRUE, `grep("^name$", c("first name", "last name", "name", "names"))`. Anyway, I use both `grep` and `%in%` :-)

Comment: correct, @akrun. Both methods are valid and which one to use depends on specific circumstances, I would say in conclusion.

Comment: I have a further question. When I do a `sqldf` query on `oldName` it works, then I do a `rename` to `newName` the same query over `newName` returns the error: no such column newName.

Comment: you have to reassign it to the data.frame to make the changes permanent: `mtcars <- rename(mtcars, cylinders = cyl)`

Comment: also note that `plyr::rename(mtcars, c(oldName = "newName"))` *would* work

Comment: @beginneR I tried `rename` and it works, except for certain columns. I have two columns: DE9 and code9, and when I do `table<-rename(table, newname = DE9)` I get `Error: found duplicated column name`. This was similar to using `grep` as mentioned by Serban elsewhere. I tried with quotes, but that threw another error.

Comment: @beginneR I see that your solution contains something that does indeed work. `plyr::rename(mtcars, c("oldName" = "newName"))`.

Comment: @Geoff, did you get the error when you tried to create a column with a name that was already existing? please try to make it reproducible

Comment: @beginneR There were two columns, one called DE9 and the other code9 and I assume that when calling by oldcolumn = DE9 it picks up both and throws the error. OTOH the `plyr` command uses quotes and that solves the problem.

Comment: @Geoff, I added a small example of what I understood you did. It works on my session without problems..

Answer (score 2):

see if this suits you

```
library(data.table)
cars = setnames(as.data.table(mtcars),
                c("mpg", "cyl", "hp"),  # old column names
                c("miles", "cylinders", "horsepower"))  # corresponding new column names
names(cars)
# [1] "miles"      "cylinders"  "disp"       "horsepower" "drat"       "wt"        
# [7] "qsec"       "vs"         "am"         "gear"       "carb"
setDF(cars) # convert back to data.frame if needed.
```

Comment: @akrun, For such task, any speed gained is negligible. But the syntax is quite easy to the eye.

Answer (score 2):

```
colnames(table)[colnames(table)=="V1"] <- "VeeOne"
```

If you want to stick to base R (data table and dplyr can be tricky for beginners, and besides, grep can misfire badly if you have similar column names), just use the above.

Full replicable example:

```
table <- matrix(1:100, ncol=10)  
colnames(table) <- paste0("V",1:10)  
colnames(table)  
colnames(table)[colnames(table)=="V1"] <- "VeeOne"  
colnames(table)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `dplyr` you are after as been posted here, as, according to the reference manual, it does not include `rename`.
It is instead plain `plyr` that includes `rename`. And it can take a name character vector for renaming:

```
library(plyr)
rename(mtcars, c("cyl"="cylinders", "mpg"="miles per gallon", "hp"="horsies"))
```